# Output works on UNO Pin 13, but not on 2?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am experimenting with IR receive and transmit (basically I want my IOT to be able to turn on the TV, satellite receiver, and set the channel - yes, I am really that lazy).

I can receive and record the remote codes, and I can transmit the codes to an IR LED.

Now for the puzzle. I originally had my IR LED on Pin 13, but to clean things up I moved the output to pin 2 and changed the pin assignment in the sketch. Now it doesn't work. My phone camera shows that the IR LED is pulsing as before, but the appliance code is not working. Moving back to pin 13 and it works again.

So, what could be different between pins 13 or 2? I know that Pin 13 has the built-in LED but since I am setting it to output that shouldn't make a difference.

I am bit-banging to create the 38kHz pulses to the IR LED, so I am wondering if there is a latency difference from pins 2 and 13?

The sketch, since I know someone will ask for it:

```cpp
int IRledPin =  13;   
int buttonPin = 4;   


void setup()   {
  pinMode(IRledPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH); // pullup
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  if (! digitalRead(buttonPin)) {
    // button down
    Serial.println("Sending IR signal");
    SendCode();
  }
}



// This procedure sends a 38KHz pulse to the IRledPin
// for a # of microseconds.
void pulseIR(long microsecs) {
  // we'll count down from the number of microseconds we are told to wait

  cli();  // this turns off any background interrupts
  while (microsecs > 0) {
    // 38 kHz is about 13 microseconds high and 13 microseconds low
    digitalWrite(IRledPin, HIGH);  // this takes about 3 microseconds
    delayMicroseconds(10);         // hang out for 10 microseconds
    digitalWrite(IRledPin, LOW);   // this also takes about 3 microseconds
    delayMicroseconds(10);         // hang out for 10 microseconds
    // so 26 microseconds altogether

    microsecs -= 26;
  }
  sei();  // this turns interrupts back on
}



void SendCode() {
  // This is the code for my FIOS FF
Serial.println("FIOS- FFwd");
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(22320);
  pulseIR(9200);
  delayMicroseconds(2240);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(24664);
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(2240);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(24684);
  pulseIR(9200);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(24684);
  pulseIR(9200);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(24664);
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);

}
```

Comment: Maybe a trivial remark, but did you change the first line: int IRledPin =  13;  to value 2?

Comment: For equivalence checking, you would need to get a logic analyzer and measure the pin signals for your D13 and D2 version. If those are exactly equivalent (and the current leaving that pin, too), I wouldn't know what else makes a difference. You could check what signal it decodes to using a standard IR decoder (http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Infrared-Remote-tutorial/) just to make sure, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```c++
void SendCode() {
  // This is the code for my FIOS FF
  Serial.println("FIOS- FFwd");
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
```

Personally I would be putting the `cli()` around everything in `SendCode` (apart from the Serial.println) because the serial print will cause interrupts, and they could occur between successive function calls there.

I checked your code using IDE 1.6.9 and got this pulse width for pin 2:

[image: Pulse width on pin 2]

And this pulse width on pin 13:

[image: Pulse width on pin 13]

You'll notice they are virtually identical and that neither show a frequency of 38 kHz. The measured period of 30.71 µs gives a frequency of 32.563 kHz.

Unless your version of the compiler generates different code than mine, I suggest you need to tweak your timing loops.

> I am wondering if there is a latency difference from pins 2 and 13?

No, I think not. The problem may be elsewhere, such as electrical. I suggest you try to measure the frequency of your timing loops using whatever external equipment you have to hand. For example, just call your pulseIR function constantly and measure with a frequency meter. I measured 32.555 kHz on my meter, for example.

---

### Use a timer to generate 38 kHz

You will get a more accurate 38 kHz signal if you use the hardware timers, properly configured. For example:

```c++
const byte LED = 10;  // Timer 1 "B" output: OC1B
const byte buttonPin = 4;

// Clock frequency divided by 38 kHz frequency desired
const long timer1_OCR1A_Setting = F_CPU / 38000L;

void setup()   {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // set up Timer 1 - gives us 38.005 kHz 
  // Fast PWM top at OCR1A
  TCCR1A = bit (WGM10) | bit (WGM11);                // fast PWM
  TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (WGM13) | bit (CS10);   // fast PWM, no prescaler
  OCR1A =  timer1_OCR1A_Setting - 1;                 // zero relative  
  OCR1B =  timer1_OCR1A_Setting / 2 - 1;             // duty cycle
}

void loop()
{
 if (! digitalRead(buttonPin)) {
    // button down
    Serial.println("Sending IR signal");
    SendCode();
    delay (200);
  }
}

// This procedure sends a 38KHz pulse to the IRledPin
// for a # of microseconds.
void pulseIR(const unsigned int microsecs) {
  TCCR1A |= bit (COM1B1); // clear OC1B on compare
  delayMicroseconds (microsecs);
  TCCR1A &= ~bit (COM1B1); // don't clear OC1B on compare
  digitalWrite (LED, LOW);
}

void SendCode() {
  // This is the code for my FIOS FF
  Serial.println("FIOS- FFwd");
  noInterrupts ();
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(4560);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(4540);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(22320);
  pulseIR(9200);
  delayMicroseconds(2240);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(24664);
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(2240);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(24684);
  pulseIR(9200);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  delayMicroseconds(24684);
  pulseIR(9200);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(540);
  delayMicroseconds(24664);
  pulseIR(9220);
  delayMicroseconds(2260);
  pulseIR(520);
  interrupts ();
}
```

This sets up Timer 1 to output 38 kHz, and then for the timing of the pulses you just turn its output on and off.

Note that you have to use D10 on your Uno because that is where Timer 1 outputs to.

---

For more information see [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers).

I have a graphic which shows a lot of the useful registers:

[image: Timer 1 information]

Comment: I know I am not supposed to say thanks here, but you have gotten me back into the books for the past two days to learn something about the Atmel chip timers.  (I hate to blindly copy code without knowing how it works).  So, if I understand correctly, Timer1 is in a free-run at 38 kHz.  The output pin is enabled with TCCR1A |= bit (COM1B1) and disabled with TCCR1A &= ~bit (COM1B1).  Do I have this right?

Comment: That's right, I've amended the answer to have a link to my page about timers, and a graphic showing various registers. With appropriate values in OCR1A and OCR1B you can set a frequency and duty cycle. In my case I made the duty cycle 50%.